# Android keyboard Resize issue

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I took over an Android project. It was created using Linear Layout. I have changed it as ConstraintLayout. Now, in any edittext, when the keyboard appears, screen design is changing.

I found that there was below code in the manifest.xml

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

I removed this line but still, my screen is resizing when the keyboard appears.

My simple xml design file is below. If I use it in a new project, there isn't any resize problem but my current project is not still working properly.

Should I look at anywhere except my desing xml and manifest.xml?

is there anyone has any idea to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_login_account"
        android:layout_width="287dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgEmailPin"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.983"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.53" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgEmailPin"
        android:layout_width="412dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.833"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.424"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgEmail"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgPin"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imgEmailPin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgEmailPin"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.157"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.12" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblEmail"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lblPin"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.22"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgEmailPin"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.100000024" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgEmailPin"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.82"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgEmailPin"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.05" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPin"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/login"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.118"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgEmailPin"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgEmailPin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.78" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblPin"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="58dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Pass"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgEmailPin"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgEmailPin"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.89" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_pin"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="43dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgEmailPin"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imgEmailPin"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgEmailPin"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.85" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
        android:layout_width="264dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="84dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgEmailPin"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.112" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblNewUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="125dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="New User"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgEmailPin"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.98" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_up"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="87dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="87dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.43"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgEmailPin"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tv_forgot_pin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        /><![CDATA[




    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="220dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="246dp" />


]]>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(path: ':vector_dev_lib')
    compile project(path: ':wheelview')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.idescout.sql:sqlscout-server:2.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your build.gradle ==> dependencies

Comment: @Zoffa please see my dependencies in below of the main question

Comment: try `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` but it would hide your toolbar if keyboard opens.

If you dont want, toolbar to be hidden when keyboard opens: **try using ScrollView**

Comment: I have tried your same exact xml and the issue is not reproduced in my device: OS version used 7.1

Answer (score 0):

1. Well, as far as you are working with `ConstraintLayout` add in the dependency:
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

   minSdkVersion 17

   targetSdkVersion 25

   versionCode 1

   versionName "1.0"

   testInstrumentationRunner

   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
2. **Sync it, Rebuild the project. it should work**

Comment: now I'm getting below error: 
`All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.3.1, 25.2.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 and com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0 more... (⌘F1) This support library should not use a lower version (25) than the targetSdkVersion (26) more... (⌘F1)`

Comment: my versions are: compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 26
        versionName "1.3.4"
        resValue "string", "tray__authority", "${applicationId}.tray"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }

Comment: How can I decide about the versions of compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, targetSdkVersion vs..) I'm very new on Android programming. I don't understand the version things of Android

Comment: it is working fine on me. maybe you will add one more library
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1' add below the above library which I have written in answer. then let me know about the logs

Comment: @MareCieco change targetSdkVersion to 25 as compileSdkVersion 25.  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0' support files should be the same version as compile sdk.

Comment: @Zoffa mate I've built the project without any error now but my keyboard/screen moving up problem still continue :(